# How to use social sharing in react native with expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a marketplace app. Users should be able to share the listing in their social accounts. How do I do this? Should be able to work with expo.

Answer (score 0):

Expo sharing only shares files, check out the documentation to see the share type is only support file input.

You can use built in share module in React Native

```
import { Share } from 'react-native';

....


Share.share({
 message: 'Something worth sharing',
 url: 'https://www.somethingtoshare.com',
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Expo provides a dependency [`expo-sharing`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v48.0.0/sdk/sharing/) which allows you to share files directly with other compatible applications.

This dependency can be installed by the following code:

```
npx expo install expo-sharing
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: isn't that for file sharing? I want to share a text with a url,img, etc. How do I do that?

Comment: No, its not just for file sharing. You can share anything with it.

Comment: mm. ok documentation is kind of not clear. But I will check.